# Getting Undefined offset: 90 while Edit Simple product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrating my website from Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.

In my backend , 
**Whenever I am trying to edit any product URL redirection, I am getting Undefined offset: 90 in**

```
vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 168.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please check `var\log` it will show you error

Comment: Checked. It looking like `main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://localhost/magento2/admin/catalog/product/save/id/1471/type/simple/store/0/set/9/key/6353b9f422941a32067700749913c9489f2d702c8527601b4e270c07f3621168/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_1471"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
` 
What it means?

Comment: It's not an error. Please make blank/empty log file & try again & put that error log in question. Also can try with Adding New Product & Edit it

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with other ID's. I was able to solve it by going to eav_attributes in the database using phpmyadmin. Look for the attribute id 90. My issue was that this id didn't exist, but the product was looking for it. If you can't find attribute_id 90 in eav_attributes, please check other product related tables for the same attribute id and delete columns when you find them.

Be sure to create a backup of your database before editting anything.

Comment: I loooked in database table. In eav_attributes table attribute_id 90 is assigned in a row. And if it is found in database. then why I am facing this error ?

Comment: Is the value of attribute_id 90 the same as in the M1 database? Check this github thread. It helped me a lot. Especially from rkhoury82 and down (commented on jun 29th). He has the same kind of error like you do. 

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5236

Comment: Can you check catalog_eav_attribute for ID 90? If it isn't there, then my first comment applies. If not, maybe the github link has some usefull information for you.

Comment: I checked catalog_eav_attribute for ID 90. Its in this table. I delete this entry and create new attribute and assigned ID 90 to this. But i am getting this error again and again while edit and saving the products.